# Domain Model Diagram

Tags: oop, object, object-oriented-analysis

Can anyone help me in domain model diagram. How can we show if condition in domain model diagram
For Example: A Student can take 4 core courses and two optional courses, if core courses are filled by students and no more available then he can take more optional courses

Answer (score 0):

In domain model we cant show if condition. In domain model we would have to represent both conditions as different entities with some attributes and with some association.